# Invalid MEX-file, "Access is denied" using matlab

Tags: windows, matlab, mex, access-denied

I've come across the following error:

> "Invalid MEX-file
>   'C:\Users\Patricia\Documents\Patricia\Winter2015\Lip
>   Reading\CFAN_Code_v1.0\resize.mexw64': Access is denied."

My permissions for the file are set to full control. 
I'm trying to run it using the same version of matlab the file was compiled on (in fact, it works fine with this version of matlab on Linux!) and I'm using the same OS it was compiled on (64 bit Windows). Though I'm not sure whether it was compiled on Windows XP, 7, or 8. Could that be the reason?

When I run depends.exe on the file, it tells me: 
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module. 
And highlights the files: 
c:\windows\system32\API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL 
c:\windows\system32\SHCORE.DLL 
c:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.DLL 
c:\windows\system32\EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL 
c:\windows\system32\EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-0.DLL 
c:\windows\system32\IEFRAME.DLL

Thank you very much for your time!! 
Pat

Comment: Do you have access to the source code? If so try to recompile.

Comment: 1) This is certainly a permissions issue; e.g. permissions on a directory, or Matlab running with a different user identity / permissions context than your normal one.  2) Do those DLLs exist?

Comment: Those missing dlls reported by Dependency Walker are normal.  It's an unrelated issue.

Comment: Thank you all!
I do not have access to the source code unfortunately (it's encrypted).
I've set all permissions of the related files and folders to full access.